# op amp circuit application

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator

I am unable to determine the function of this circuit. The second stage looks like an integrator, but the presence of a pot in stage 1 really confuses me...

[image: Circuit]

Comment: The way the pot is connected is sometimes called a *rheostat*, it turns it into a variable resistance instead of the more common voltage divider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a variable frequency oscillator with a triangle wave output at Vb. The first amplifier is used as a comparator (so only some op-amps would be suitable) with hysteresis set by the saturation voltages of the amplifier and R1/R2 ratio.

The square wave output of the comparator is fed to the integrator.

The period will be determined by the time it takes for the integrator to slew between the two transition voltages of the comparator. If the saturation voltages of the comparator are close to each other (implying usually that the positive and negative supply voltages are fairly close, perhaps with a bit bigger positive supply for a 'single supply' op amp) then the triangle wave will be fairly symmetrical and the square wave close to 50% duty cycle.

The period will be proportional to the sum of the 100K pot resistance plus R, so the frequency will be proportional to the reciprocal of the pot rotation angle from 0 ohms, ignoring R. That means it might be quite nonlinear (if you had R=1K ohms, and the frequency went from 100Hz to ~10kHz, the bottom 1% part of the pot resistance would change the frequency from 5kHz to 10kHz).

Comment: Correct, left opamp is a Schmitt-trigger providing current to a current integrator formed by the right side opamp + C. Turning the 100k pot will change the integrator charge/discharge current and thus changing the frequency.

Comment: Also note that  R2 should be much bigger than R1. But not too much bigger.